# Eclipse and PDT: I can not type f letter anymore

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-pdt

Sorry if it appears as stupid question, but really I can not work anymore, and this is ... sad.
Eclipse continue to assign F to format code (Menu->Source->Format). I found a way to reset to default, but suddenly after switching to other window (browser) eclipse restore the key binding. I can go back anymore.

Is there a quick direction to follow to make it work as before? there is something that could cause this to happen? what? a key sequence? it worked until now, where do I look for a possible cause of such a weird behavior?

I do changed file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so (s/Eclipse/Xclipse/) for ubuntu menu, could it had caused the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The last question lead to a conclusion: yes it is related to main menu issue.

So disable it with

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies
sudo sed -i 's/Xclipse/Eclipse/' libappmenu.so

I think discussion should be continued here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/618587